# Odoo version 13: Adding Subscription Lines using automated actions

Tags: python, odoo, product, subscription

I am trying to use automated actions to add subscription lines to an existing subscription when one or more source records are created.

The quantity field from the source (record.x_studio_prod_qty) is populating correctly. Just not the product_id. It seems to default to the first product that appears alphabetically. The full code is below:

```
prod_int_id = record.x_studio_ret_prod_id

subscription_check = env['product.product'].search([('product_variant_id', '=', int(prod_int_id)),('recurring_invoice', '=', True)], limit=1)

subscription_header = env['sale.subscription'].search([('x_studio_parent_code', '=', 
record.x_studio_parent_number)], limit=1)

add_subscription_check = {
            'product_id': subscription_check.product_variant_ids[0].id,
            'uom_id': subscription_check.uom_id.id,
            'price_unit': subscription_check.list_price,
            'quantity': record.x_studio_prod_qty
        }    
subscription_header.write({'recurring_invoice_line_ids':[(5, 0, 0),(0,0,add_subscription_check)]})
```

It works fine if the product_id is hardcoded in (as below) however, that defeats the purpose.....

```
'product_id': "800",
```

I have cobbled information together from other posts to get this far so would appreciate this final hurdle getting resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Bamidele

Use `id` instead of the  `product_variant_id` on the `domain` while you search the product id.

```
subscription_check = env['product.product'].search([('id', '=', int(prod_int_id)),('recurring_invoice', '=', True)], limit=1)
```

The field `product_variant_id` having on the template level to access the product but here you're getting the product id and also with a search on the product.
Also, make sure that the computed field can not use and return the data on a search is it is not `store true`.

Comment: Hello Dipen, thank you for your input. regarding the computed field and store true, which fields are you referring to exactly?

Comment: I'm concern for this 'product_variant_id' field.

Comment: I have removed the product_variant_id field and am using the id field as suggested. The behaviour is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to use automated action references and values all the way instead of python.